# Linq to SQL Designer: Making Image types byte[] by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to Sql to query a number of database tables. In these tables there are a good few uses of the `Image` data type.

When using the DBML designer I drag and drop my tables, and any fields that use the `Image` data type are mapped as `System.Data.Linq.Binary` when the classes are generated. However, I want these to be `Byte[]`.

Currently, this is a manual process or changing the field type in the designer, and in all fairness is not that time consuming in the grand scale of things, but I would prefer if this was done automatically for me.

Is there a way that this can be done? Some sort of Linq to Sql setting?

The main annoyance for me is when I make changes to a table that I need to re-add, and then I have to change the fields back to `byte[]`

Comment: What if change **Image** data type to **varBinary** ?

Comment: @Mazdak_SH: Its not an issue with type conversion as that works fine between DB and DataContext. But I need byte[] at the client level and I also use null, which has proven to be a pain as the DataContext doesn't seem to want to store as null in the DB while it uses binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) has a template that generates linq-to-SQL classes from the DBML that is easily customized, including changing the default type mappings.

Comment: It certainly looks promising, but I am a little put of by the seemingly large amount of set-up work. I will persist and see how I get on though

Comment: It is a bit of setup, but if you are having to change these tables a lot it could be worth it. It's a lot less work than switching to EF or some other tool.